# Accessing req.session object when writing tests that use supertest

Tags: node.js, express, supertest

I have just started using `supertest` and `nock` to write unit tests for middleware in my express application.

All requests handled by my router setup are first checked for the presence of a session property (I am using express-session).

```
app.use('/api', helpers.hasAccessToken, require('./routes.js'));
```

The helper simply does:

```
module.exports.hasAccessToken = function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.session.accessToken){
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).send('LOGIN_SESSION_ENDED');
  }
};
```

In my test spec I have:

```
var app = require('./index.js'),
  request = require('supertest')(app),
  expect = require('chai').expect,
  nock = require('nock');


    describe('GET requests', function(){
      beforeEach(function(){
        nock('https://somedomain:port')
          .get('/someendpoint')
          .reply(200, {foo:'bar'});
      });
      it('should return a 200 HTTP status code', function(done){
        request
          .get('/api/someendpoint')
          .end(function(err, res){
            expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
            done();
          });
      });
    });
```

This errors with a status of 401 being returned instead, which I know is down to the `req.session.accessToken` property not having been set prior to the tests being run.

So how can I get at the `req` object to do what I like with the session object?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The workflow is: user sign in => set `req.session.accessToken` in server-side => response to client-side with `set-cookie` response header(cookie set by `express-session`) => call protected `/api/someendpoint` endpoint with `accessToken` cookie. => call `hasAccessToken` middleware => rest code logic.

Here is the solution:

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const helpers = require("./helpers");
const app = express();

app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  }),
);

app.post("/signin", (req, res) => {
  req.session.accessToken = "123123";
  console.info("signin success");
  res.status(200).end();
});

app.use("/api", helpers.hasAccessToken, require("./routes"));

const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.info(`HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:${server.address().port}`);
});

module.exports = server;
```

`helpers.js`:

```js
module.exports.hasAccessToken = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("req.session.accessToken", req.session.accessToken);
  if (req.session.accessToken) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).send("LOGIN_SESSION_ENDED");
  }
};
```

`routes.js`:

```js
const { Router } = require("express");

const router = Router();

router.get("/someendpoint", (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

module.exports = router;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const app = require("./app");
const request = require("supertest");
const expect = require("chai").expect;

describe("GET requests", function() {
  const agent = request(app);
  let cookies;

  before((done) => {
    agent.post("/signin").expect(200, (err, res) => {
      if (err) return done(err);
      expect(res.headers).to.have.property("set-cookie");
      cookies = res.headers["set-cookie"].pop().split(";")[0];
      done();
    });
  });
  after((done) => {
    app.close(done);
  });

  it("should return a 200 HTTP status code", function(done) {
    console.log(cookies);
    agent
      .get("/api/someendpoint")
      .set("Cookie", [cookies])
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Integration test result with coverage report:

```sh
HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:3000
  GET requests
signin success
connect.sid=s%3Ahw94RpxRocC4hMTkCmMx4Ot85aGYG6s5.eE91ELDNjuQ1fWqEsRZdwtwKokLXR6%2Bao9NGdvl%2Bflc
req.session.accessToken 123123
    ✓ should return a 200 HTTP status code


  1 passing (33ms)

-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File         |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files    |    93.33 |       50 |      100 |    97.67 |                   |
 app.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.test.js |    90.48 |       50 |      100 |      100 |             11,27 |
 helpers.js  |       80 |       50 |      100 |       80 |                 6 |
 routes.js   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/39118250